# How do i pull code to my branch without breaking the code? On github, my branch has 11 commits ahead, and 17 commits behind

Tags: git, github, terminal

If I do a basic git pull, will it then be 11 commits ahead, and 0 commits behind?

How do I fetch the commits that are behind without breaking the code?

[image]

Comment: Why do you think something will break? Just pull and test. If ok, push. If not, fix (and then push). If you are sharing a branch, or if you are trying to bring a feature branch up to date before pushing to a PR, you have no choice. You cannot push to a branch that has commits you don't have; that's just a fact. You have to deal with it.

Comment: Here's a mental model to try: your branch has 11 commits that dev doesn't have, but dev has 17 commits that your branch doesn't have. This is common with branches. With that in mind, what is your current goal?

Comment: @JakeWorth my goal is to be 11 commits ahead, 0 commits behind dev

Comment: @jabinx92 merge dev into your branch, or rebase your branch on top of dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When two people are working on the same branch, so that the branch gets ahead on the remote, there is absolutely no guarantee that things you have done will not "break" when you pull. You just have to bite the bullet and do it, and see what happens. Presumably you have tests for everything *you* have been doing. So pull, then test. If all is well, fine. If not, fix. That's just life. It's what you have to do.

Keep in mind that if you do a normal pull and things *do* break, you can always back your own local branch out of the merge that the pull performed. But sooner or later you *will* have to pull, so you might as well get used to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `git pull --rebase`, which will (try to) rebase your 11 changes on top of the latest 17 changes from upstream.

Depending on how confident you are in successfully resolving any conflicts that might arise during this process, it might be worth creating a branch before you do this, so you have your current branch state even if things go wrong.